# T-SQL Delete Inserted Records

Tags: t-sql, select, output, sql-insert, sql-delete

I know the title may seem strange but this is what I want to do:

1. I have table with many records.
2. I want to get some of this records and insert them in other table. Something like this:

   `INSERT INTO TableNew SELECT * FROM TableOld WHERE ...`
3. The tricky part is that I want this rows that I have inserted to be deleted form the origin table as well.

Is there a easy way to do this, because the only think that I have managed to do is to use a temporary table for saving the selected records and then to put them in the second table and delete rows that match with them from the first table. It is a solution, but with so many records (over 3 millions and half) I am looking for some other idea...

Comment: use the OUTPUT clause...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In 2005+ use `OUTPUT` clause like this:

```
DELETE FROM TableOld 
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO TableNew
WHERE YourCondition
```

It will be performed in single transaction and either completed or roll back simultaneously

Comment: Don't know if I can resurrect this, but is there a way to do this when you have an identity column in the source and destination tables?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [insert ... output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to store the ID's of the copied rows in a temporary table.  Then you can delete the rows from the original table based on the temporary table.

```
declare @Table1 table (id int, name varchar(50))
declare @Table2 table (id int, name varchar(50))

insert @Table1 (id,name)
          select 1, 'Mitt'
union all select 2, 'Newt'
union all select 3, 'Rick'
union all select 4, 'Ron'


declare @copied table (id int)

insert  @Table2
        (id, name)
output  inserted.id 
into    @copied
select  id
,       name
from    @Table1
where   name <> 'Mitt'

delete  @Table1
where   id in 
        (
        select  id 
        from    @copied
        )
        
select  *
from    @Table1
```

[Working example at Data Explorer.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59947/new)

Answer (score 0):

You should do some thing like this:

```
INSERT INTO "table1" ("column1", "column2", ...)
SELECT "column3", "column4", ...
FROM "table2" 
WHERE ...

DELETE FROM "table1"
WHERE ...
```