# Optimising SQL Procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two table **Old_Table** and **New_Table**. My old table has 13 million records in it currently and I need to process the data in old table and dump it into new. Data will be continuously inserted into my old table. So, I wrote a stored procedure and created a sql job to run nightly and process the data that is inserted into the old table for that day.

My procedure is taking hell lot of a time. Like, my procedure need to process 13 million records per day and the sql job is running never endingly since it started. How can I optimise my below procedure to make it faster

```
select @From = Max(InsertTime) From [New_Table];
set @To = GETDATE(); 

declare @ID as int;
set @ID = 0;

SET @ID = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM Old_Table where TimeStamp > @From and TimeStamp < @To)


WHILE @ID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    --Get the row data
    SELECT @col1 = COLUMN1,
           @col2 = case when CHARINDEX('?', COLUMN2) > 0 
                              THEN SUBSTRING(COLUMN2, 1,CHARINDEX('?', COLUMN2)-1)
                              else COLUMN2 
                         END,
           @col3 = [dbo].[ModifyString] (COLUMN3) 
    from Old_Table with(nolock)
    where Id = @ID;

            --Few if conditions
                    select @rowID = ID from [dbo].[New_Table] with(nolock)
                    where [COL1] = @col1 and [COL2] = @col2 and [COL3] = @col3

            --If exists update the row else insert as new row
            If @rowID > 0
            Begin
                -- Update my New_Table
            End
            Else
            Begin
                -- Insert into my new table
            End

            --delete from Old_Table
            delete from [dbo].[Old_Table] where id = @ID


    --Fetch next record
    SET @ID = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM Old_Table where TimeStamp > @From and TimeStamp < @To);
END
```

My function `[dbo].[ModifyString]` has 5 IF conditions which uses `CHARINDEX` and `STUFF` functions with in it.

Adding Table defenitions:

```
    [New_Table](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  --Primary Key
    [COL1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [COL2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [COL3] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Count] [int] NULL,
    [TimeImported] [datetime] NULL,  -- Non-Clustered Index
    [COL5_NEW] [bit] NULL,
    [COL6_NEW] [bit] NULL,
    [COL7_NEW] [bit] NULL,



[Old_Table]( 
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, -- Primary Key
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,  -- Non-Clustered Index
    [COL1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [COL2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [COL3] [varchar](max) NULL,
```

Edit: My old table has duplicate records and [Count] in the new table needs to be incremented for each duplicate record in the old table.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the query execution plan to see which part of the query is the bottleneck? Also posting table definitions including indexes may help.

Comment: Classic RBAR (row by agonizing row) code.  :<

Comment: Please consider posting this on http://dba.stackexchange.com for a better targeted audience.

Comment: you mentioned old_table has 13M rows and everyday new records coming in. during processing and dumping in to new table you just process data that loaded today. so what is an average daily new data being loaded. if storage space is not an critical issue, I would suggest to dump daily data in staging area as well and let the nightly job run off from that. after job finishes clear that staging area for new day. if the job fails or not run for a day or so at max you would have 1 to 3 days worth data in staging area instead 13M+ data everyday.

Comment: @AnupShah I don't query 13M records every day. I am starting a new job to clean up the data in the old table and once it is done with all the historical data before the given todate, it will only deal with the records inserted into it for the current day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the query to set-based operations. I see nothing preventing that from working. Iteration-based code is not recommended in T-SQL for performance and maintainability reasons.

You can either use the `MERGE` statement to execute all changes at once, or run one `insert`, `update` and `delete` statement.

I see no reason why you cannot update all 13 million records in one (or three) statements. This will realize huge efficiency gains (orders of magnitude).

Comment: yes sure, DB queries should be written in set fashion as long as possible. yet I see another issue being why would I query 13M table everyday. if I have to process only daily Data.

Comment: @PushCode you can use the MERGE statement to update the `Count` column in case the target row already exists. Are you familiar with the MERGE statement? Look into it, it is made for what you want.

Comment: @usr I was not aware of MERGE. It seems like the one I need for this scenario. I'll give it a shot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Loops are no bueno in SQL.  Avoid them if you can...  This psudocode should get you started down the right road:

```
--Insert new
INSERT INTO NewTable
   SELECT * FROM OldTable
   EXCEPT 
   SELECT * FROM NewTable

--Update existing
UPDATE NewTable as nt
   INNER JOIN OldTable as ot
      ON nt.id = ot.id
SET nt.value = ot.value
```

Most modern DBMSs are designed to handle set based operations so if you see a loop you can expect performance problems.

Comment: I made an edit to my original question. How can I take duplicate records into consideration with out looping through the data set?

Answer (score 1):

As well as the RBAR others have mentioned (which needs addressing), you're also searching New_Table for a match against 3 varchar(MAX) fields, which aren't indexable.

I'd suggest adding OldTableID as an indexed int column to New_Table, then amending the script to use it as the link (populating it as part of the MERGE or INSERT used) instead of the three varchar columns (as well as sorting the RBAR). An index on Old_Table.TimeStamp would also help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a template for the insert

```
insert into New_Table 
SELECT  Old_Table.ID, Old_Table.COLUMN1,
        case when CHARINDEX('?', Old_Table.COLUMN2) > 0 
                              THEN SUBSTRING(Old_Table.COLUMN2, 1,CHARINDEX('?', COLUMN2)-1)
                              else Old_Table.COLUMN2 
                         END,
        Old_Table.[ModifyString] (COLUMN3) 
 from Old_Table 
 left join New_Table
   on Old_Table.[COL1] = New_Table.[COL1] 
  and Old_Table.[COL2] = New_Table.[COL2]
  and Old_Table.[COL3] = New_Table.[COL3]
where Old_Table,TimeStamp > @From and Old_Table.TimeStamp < @To 
  and New_Table.ID is null
```

See this for combining the delete and insert
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968498/t-sql-delete-inserted-records)

Then the update is a join (no left) and no New_Table.ID is null